# What is a good expression vector for Salmonella enterica subsp. enterica serovar typhimurium

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, plasmids, protein-expression, biomedical-engineering

I am interested in expressing custom proteins in a Salmonella strain, however I am facing difficulties in finding the appropriate expression vector for it. It seems that most of the resources provide for E. coli expression. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to do this in Salmonella?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to e.g. express fluorescent proteins for doing some kind of experimental study of Salmonella, as opposed to industrial protein production.

I would suggest looking into prior work that uses Salmonella as a model. For example, I found [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1230934/) somewhat at random that uses several vectors in Salmonella to do experiments. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3148252/) is another. And [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep30591) is another. Several of these appear to share authors, I don't know if that's Google SEO or a small research community.